# New logcat Android Studio Dolphin: how to show errors only for My app

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-studio-dolphin

With the new Logcat for AS Dolphin, I'm using the filter:

```
level:error
```

and it shows me the errors in the logcat, however, it shows all errors that are happing in the phone,but I just want the errors for my app, I have tried also this:

```
package:mine || level:error
```

But it doesn't work at all. Have you found a way to do this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: use space ` ` instead of this `||`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use space instead of **||** operator.
I tried it on my project, it shows only error log correctly.

```
package:mine level:error
```